# Issue with Retrieving SAML Assertion attributes in request header

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to implement SAML Based SP Initiated Single-sign on using openSSO. Post the authentication request validated on IdP side, it passes the SAMLResponse via post redirect to 
spAssertionConsumer.jsp to SP. Till this point I am getting the SAML Response. As we are using Sun Java System Web Server, I have installed the respective policy agent, and in Session Attributes Processing I have mapped the required attributes as well.

I have mentioned the Relay State URL as my application URL which is a separate domain from the openSSO installed one. When the response getting redirected from openSSO to our application I am not getting any SAML Assertion attributes in request header or Cookies.

I am not sure what probably would have gone wrong here> If anyone provides some clarification on it, its highly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand - there's no issue with the AuthenticationRequest, or the response... 

The issue is passing the attributes of the assertion from OpenSSO to your application - and the application is in a separate domain (e.g., application._bob_.com) than the OpenSSO server (e.g., opensso._john_.com).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug de SAML flow I recomend you to use the [SAML Tracer plugin for firefox][1]

There are a lot of things that could be failing. Review that the IdP is sending a SUCCESS status, that the assertion of the response has the expected attributes, check that the response is valid, check if is there any sign or encryption that the SP can't handle

If not wrong data detected, I recomend you to create a basic app under the domain of the openSSO and check if this app retrieve the attributes, due other problem that could been happen is that you final app is not getting the attributes due can't read the session that was stored by OpenSSO.

Usually the SP software is located at the same machine of the final software in order to share the session...but you could store the session at the OpenSSO at a shared memcached server that is accessed by your final app

[1] https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/